# Как возникает эта странная иллюзия?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle

Я написал этот скрипт сегодня и был удивлен этими белыми линиями. Я хотел бы знать, как они появляются

```
#code
from turtle import *

speed(9999999999)
penup()
rt(100)
fd(348)
lt(100)
pendown()

for i in range(1000):
    circle(i)
```

[image]

Comment: Это русскоязычное сообщество, либо задавайте вопрос на русском языке, либо используйте англоязычный ресурс

Comment: Перевод пожалуйста

Comment: Нет, отредактируйте сам вопрос и там всё по-русски напишите.